# Calculate child object values and show on parent

Tags: arrays, angularjs

Assume this is some data that i want to publish in my AngularJS view (dutch language):

```
    $scope.data =
    [
        {
            name: "actief",
            value: null,
            children:
            [
                {
                    name: "vast actief",
                    value: [20, 30, 40, 50],
                    children: null
                },
                {
                    name: "vlottend actief",
                    value: [215, 230, 245, 500],
                    children: null
                },
                {
                    name: "bewegend actief",
                    value: [134, 135, 136, 137],
                    children: null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "stilstaand",
            value: null,
            children:
            [
                {
                    name: "vast stilstaand",
                    value: [2000, 3000, 4000, 5000],
                    children: null
                },
                {
                    name: "vlottend stilstaand",
                    value: [2150, 2300, 2450, 5000],
                    children: null
                },
                {
                    name: "bewegend stilstaand",
                    value: [1340, 1350, 1360, 1370],
                    children: null
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

To publish this object in a list on my view i can do something like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in data">
    <li>{{item.name}}</li>
    <ul ng-repeat="child in item.children">
        <li>{{ child.name }}</li>
        <ul ng-repeat="value in child.value">
            <li>{{ value }}</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I want my parent object `{{ item name }}` to have a array with the sum of the children e.g. the first parent would have this array: `[369, 395, 421, 687]`

I tried to do this calculation inside my controller (i know, no logic in the controller but it's just for testing)

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++){
    $scope.data[i].value = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.data[i].children.length; j++) {
        if ($scope.data[i].children[j].value.length > 0) {
            for (var k = 0; k < $scope.data[i].children[j].value.length; k++) {
                console.log(typeof $scope.data[i].children[j].value[k]); // says number!
                $scope.data[i].value[k] += $scope.data[i].children[j].value[k]; // But my array is NAN???
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are 4 positions in my parent value array, but al of them are `NaN`, what am i doing wrong?

**Side Question**:

because i'm doing the looping in my view, isn't there a shorter way to calculate the totals of the array position there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax

```
$scope.data[i].value[k] += ... // some value
```

assumes that there is already a value in the array's `k` position to increment.

In your code, the array is initially empty. What is happening is something like this:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray[0] += 1; // error: there is no element at the 0 position!
```

One way to solve this problem is to initialize the empty array with zero values:

```
$scope.data[i].value = [0, 0, 0, 0]; // you can also seed the initial zeroes using a loop
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? because when i do `var myArray = []; myArray += 5` i just get `5`. But when i do `var myArray = []; myArray += 5; myArray += 10` i get `510`. What i see is that it not counts the numbers but concat them.

Comment: From my understanding of your question, what you want to do is increment a value inside the array, which has the syntax `myArray[index] += value`. So if you have `var myArray = [1,2,3]` and you want to add `5` to the first element, you would do `myArray[0] += 5`. Notice the use of the index `0`. The syntax without the index (`myArray += 5`) is not what you're looking for in this case.

Comment: You're right and i was waiting till i could edit my previous answer, because i have noticed that! We'll it works, thank you very much!